# disable assets compilation on heroku for debugging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, development-environment

I'm using a heroku instance for production, and another for staging. I would like my assets to not be compiled on my staging instance for easier team debugging. I see [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#compiling-assets-locally) that I can disable assets compilation by having a manifest.yml file in my project.

My question, is there anyway to have rails include or exclude a file based on the environment I choose?

Comment: Are you trying to have precompiled assets or serve the raw assets?

Comment: @AJcodez I want the raw assets served. The same way they are in the local development environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use debug settings like in the development config and get rid of all other lines mentioning assets:

```
# config/environments/staging.rb
config.assets.debug = true
```

Use the rails_12factor gem so heroku will serve the assets:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'rails_12factor'
```

---

**Edit**:

On heroku you can set the environment with:

```
$ heroku config:set --remote staging RACK_ENV=staging RAILS_ENV=staging
```

Assuming you deploy to multiple environments and called the staging one "staging". Make sure your Procfile which specifies the start command does not specify the environment.

Comment: awesome. Could you show how enable/specify the staging environment?